# jQuery that works in Firefox but not in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok guys/girls.

Below is some jQuery that runs in Firefox but no IE. I have no idea why it craps out in one and not the other.

Anyone??

```
function SwapTextAssetforPOS() {

    $("*").each(function () {

        if ($(this).children().length == 0) {

            $(this).text($(this).text().replace('Assets', 'POS'));
            $(this).text($(this).text().replace('Asset', 'POS'));
            $(this).text($(this).text().replace('assets', 'POS'));
            $(this).text($(this).text().replace('asset', 'POS'));

        }

    });

}
```

Sorry folks - the error that I get is:-

**SCRIPT65535: Unexpected call to method or property access. 
jquery-1.6.min.js, line 16 character 60352**

**EDIT:------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Ok so an update - I removed the * selector and IE no longer blows up, my issue now is that I cant figure how to get it to do the replace on the element. I have the following code to ping up all the text elements in the object:

```
function SwapTextAssetforPOS() {
        var containerElementByID = $("#assetDetailContents");

        containerElementByID.children().children().each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);

            alert($this.text());


        });
```

This chucks me up an alert for every bit of text, however some is contained within a table, some is within a span, and some is just there. I have no control over a majority of this stuff so my new question is how do I get the previous replace to work using this type of selector. -- I can believe how painful this is..

Cheers again

Comment: Are you getting an error? Or is the script not running at all?

Comment: Can you explain the function in detail?  It seems like there should be a better way than to nest `$(this).text()` inside of `$(this).text()`

Comment: IE's support for the global selector in `document.getElementsByTagName` is spotty at best. You may be tripping up there.

Comment: that's interesting regarding the global selector - I guess i should go with a get all div??

Answer (score 3):

I see the problem in my IE browser. When you do the `$("*").each`...  it takes every single element in the page (including title, script, etc). When you do `.text()`, looks like it fails for some elements in IE for which .text() doesn't make sense.  Replace "*" for "div" and it should work for the divs for example.
Maybe you could do something like
 `if ($(this).text()) {$(this).text($(this).text().replace('Assets', 'POS'));}` to make sure the text() is defined for that element.
Still, going through the whole DOM is overkill. Can you add a class to the elements that can have the text?, like `class="replaceable"` so you could just do a `$(".replaceable").text(...`

Comment: maybe I can put it on the container div for the overlay . will report back on that one.

Answer (score 1):

Ok folks - so firstly thanks for the help.

I have resolved the issue by cobbling a number of suggestions together and by doing a little bit of investigative work.

In a nutshell IE was crapping out when it ran up against an  tag. I no not why but this is where it fell over every time.

```
function SwapTextAssetforPOS() {

        var overlaycon = $("#jq-selectionHelper").find("*:not(img)"); //This line simply looks at the div surrounding the template and returns (to an array I believe) every element therein except for img tag
                                                                      //as this breaks in IE when tying to do the replace text stuff below. 

        overlaycon.each(function () {

            var $this = $(this);

            if ($this.children().length == 0) {
                $this.text($(this).text().replace('Assets', 'POS'));
                $this.text($(this).text().replace('Asset', 'POS'));
                $this.text($(this).text().replace('assets', 'POS'));
                $this.text($(this).text().replace('asset', 'POS'));
            }
        });
    }
```

This code runs and I believe is a lot more efficient than my original offering. Any further suggestions for performance re-factoring are welcome but thank the lord this is now working.

Thanks again for all the help.

Regards

Comment: $this.text($this.text().replace(/asset(s?)/gi,"POS");

Answer (score 0):

This code has no problem as seen here . I tested in IE and FF both works fine

```
http://jsfiddle.net/wKWRC/
```

You should use F12 developer tool for IE and see what error you are getting that way others can know what exact problem is . You can debug script and see where you are getting error . IE is sensitive to javascript errors and its possible there is some error before you are calling this function .

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699336%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to jsfiddle - never knew it existed until now but it's on my favourites already.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch but you might be running out of memory in IE.

First, using `$('*')` is never advisable, its better that you narrow it down with a selector like `$('p')`.

Also, every time you call $(this) you create a new jQuery object, so if there are a lot of elements on your page you're making 9 objects every time.

The convention is to set `$this = $(this)` at the begining of the function so you only use one object.

```
function SwapTextAssetforPOS() {

    $("*").each(function () {

        var $this = $(this);

        if ($this.children().length == 0) {

            $this.text($this.text().replace('Assets', 'POS'));
            $this.text($this.text().replace('Asset', 'POS'));
            $this.text($this.text().replace('assets', 'POS'));
            $this.text($this.text().replace('asset', 'POS'));

        }

    });

}
```

Comment: I suspect this is correct.  If I change the selector so that it doesn't select EVERYthing on the page (change "*" to "#someDiv *"), it works fine.  That change doesn't affect the logic, but it greatly reduces the number of elements which will be looped-over by the .each function.

Comment: No this is not the case. My test page showed the error and it only had two elements in the body

Comment: @Rodolfo, I agree the `$(*)` is definitely overkill but so is making 9 jQuery objects. I'll update my answer to reflect this

Comment: Oh I agree with you 100%, I just meant that this is not what's causing the problem, but yes the code can be improved by factoring $this

Answer (score 0):

try it like this

```
for (var i = 0, replacements = ['Assets','assets','asset','Asset']; i < 4; i++)
    $("*:contains('" + replacements[i] +"')").map(function() { this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(/asset(s){0,1}/igm, 'POS'); })
```